# Why should the ECN on your machine be disabled?

Tags: iptables, notifications

I was going through [this article](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/linux-24-stateful-fw-design.xml) on iptables and there the author said that:

> It's important to turn off ECN (explicit congestion notification) so
>   that Internet communications will work properly.

Why do we need to disable the ECN?

Comment: That article is for the 2.4 kernel version. Maybe it's a bit dated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There used to be a lot of broken routers out there that would drop any packets with the ECN bits set. I remember trying it and experiencing this personally. [This site](http://icir.org/floyd/ecnProblems.html) gives you a taste of how things used to be, particularly the "8% of the internet unreachable!" link. It's of roughly the same vintage as the article you linked; as Mat pointed out, the article describes Linux 2.4, and 2.6 was released in 2003...

Even now, years later, I wouldn't be too surprised to hear of broken routers still out there given that ECN still ships disabled on major platforms (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification#Implementations)). So you could turn on ECN, forget about it entirely, and later be unable to visit some site without knowing why.